# Set nginx init script to never run automatically on startup

Tags: upstart, systemd, runlevel

I just installed nginx on Ubuntu 16.04. The trouble is, I only want to start it manually, never automatically on runlevel.

I found lots of entries about how to get it to run on different runlevels, but not to prevent running on all of them.

So, I guessed and did this:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:   nginx
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named
# Default-Start:
# Default-Stop:      0 1 2 3 4 5 6
# Short-Description: starts the nginx web server
# Description:       starts nginx using start-stop-daemon
### END INIT INFO
```

Then:

```
/etc/init.d$ sudo update-rc.d nginx defaults
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (2 3 4 5) of script `nginx' overrides LSB defaults (empty).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 6) of script `nginx' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 2 3 4 5 6).
```

which looks to me like my changes didn't work.

How do I shut this off?

Comment: `update-rc.d` is Upstart / SysVInit, and default 16.04 is SystemD, are you using SystemD for your init system, or the older ones?

Comment: @ThomasWard sorry, didn't know that it wasn't upstart.

Comment: No problem!  I've written an answer for SystemD, but without knowing how you installed nginx, it may or may not work.  Did you install from the repositories, or from the PPA (`apt` / `apt-get`), or did you install from source code (download the source code and compile)?

Comment: @ThomasWard Sorry, I installed using apt-get.

Comment: then you should be good with the answer below.  If not, let me know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This answer assumes you are using the default init system in 16.04, which is SystemD.

Borrowing from [DigitalOcean's SystemD guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units), you can disable nginx autoboot with this:

```
sudo systemctl disable nginx.service
```

This should disable autostart of the service at boot like the older `update-rc.d` functionality provided.  (Note that with SystemD, `update-rc.d` isn't going to be as useful)

Comment: I get the error "Excess Arguments"

Comment: @Thom I provided the wrong command - please check again and see if the updated command works.